# Reference for Chebyshev centers

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, ho.history-overview, geometric-group-theory

Today, I came across the concept of [Chebyshev center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center) twice.

In particular, it is the key tool in the very elegant paper ["A fixed point theorem for $L^1$ spaces"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00222-011-0363-2) by Bader, Gelander and Monod.

Why is this concept named after Chebyshev?

Answer (score 6):

The name "Chebyshev center" was introduced by Garkavi [1], for the relationship to the Cheybshev approximation problem (minimize the maximum error). Garkavi refers to a 1951 paper by Zukhovitskii for this connection [2].

[image]

<sub>An important special case of the problem of the best $N$-network is the problem of the smallest sphere containing a given set (i.e., the case $N=1$). We will call the center of the smallest sphere containing the set $M$ the *Chebyshev center* of this set [cf. (2), (8)].</sub>

---

[1] A. L. Garkavi, [On the optimal net and best cross-section of a set in a normed space](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3188&option_lang=eng), Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat., 1962, Volume 26, Issue 1, 87–106.

[2] S.I. Zukhovitskii, *Algorithm for finding the point that least deviates (in the sense of Chebyshev) from a given system of $n$ points*, Reports Ak. Sciences of the Ukrainian SSR, 6 (1951), 404-407.